# print lines with specific condition on the last field of each line into another file

Tags: linux, loops, awk, sed

I have multiple files and one of the file with 4 lines like below

```
2345,abdgdhf,......,12879
6354, kfsjgdh,.....,"fac
74573,khskdd,......,5663
gffhf,gfgfhfh,......,7675
```

I want to write lines where the first field is not digits or the first character of last field is quotation into another file. the expected output should be a file with two lines as below

```
6354, kfsjgdh,.....,"fac
gffhf,gfgfhfh,......,7675
```

The command below will print the lines where the first field is not a number

```
for f in *.csv; do 
    awk -F "," '(/^[^0-9]/) {print }' "$f" > ./bad/"$f"
done
```

Output will be

```
gffhf,gfgfhfh,......,7675
```

And the command below will give me the fist character of last field
`awk -F "," '{print ($(NF))}'   <file> |sed 's/\(.\{1\}\).*/\1/'`
Output will be

```
1
"
5
7
```

I don't know how to merge this line into my for loop and add a condition to only grab lines with quotation as the first character of last field to have first line of `6354, kfsjgdh,.....,"fac` in expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop:

```
awk -F',' '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out="./bad/" FILENAME }
    ($1 !~ /^[0-9]+$/) || ($NF ~ /^"/) { print > out }
' *.csv
```

Comment: thanks. I have multiple files and wanted to do the same for all. I edited my question

Comment: Yes, I understood that and as I mentioned you do not need a loop to do so. Run exactly the command I posted and it will work for all of your files at once.